# The broker is not responding to the connection request message correctly The return code is MqttConnectReturnCode.notAuthorized

Tags: flutter, mqtt

I'm trying to connect my Flutter App with mqtt broker but unfortunately this happened. May I know why this happened??

[log] mqtt-client::NoConnectionException: The maximum allowed connection attempts ({3}) were exceeded. The broker is not responding to the connection request message correctly The return code is MqttConnectReturnCode.notAuthorized

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74064238/edit) the question to show both the code that sets up the connection and details of the how the broker you are using is configured. As it is there is not enough information to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You exceeded your login attempts for connecting Mqtt, this issue is related to your

```
 MQTT client
```

it only give you three attepts to log in correctly ,after that it will close the login

you need to fix it by using

```
MQTT client setting
```

Comment: is this setting can also solve the "MqttConnectReturnCode.notAuthorized" ??

Comment: yes not authorized mean you cant access it because you trired more than three attempt you need fix it on mqtt client

Comment: I'm sorry for the longest thank you reply ever. but Thank you so much. I just need to put my client ID and this issue solved. Thank you once again!